# Pig javascript does not fire

Tags: javascript, apache-pig

I have copied the following JavaScript from Pig Latin site and created firstJS.js file

```
helloworld.outputSchema = "(word:chararray)" 
function helloworld() { 
    return 'Hello, World'; 
}
```

The script is Registered as follows:

```
register '/cloudera/examples/javascripts/firstJS.js' using javascript as myfuncs;
```

The JavaScript is called in Pig as follows:

//Loading the data

```
student = LOAD '/cloudera/examples/Students.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray);
```

//Calling the JavaScript function in Pig Statement

```
B = foreach student generate myfuncs.helloworld();
```

//ERROR Received

```
 ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myfuncs.helloworld using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Question:
What am I doing wrong? Can somebody give me a working, complete and small example of using JavaScript with Pig. I am not sure what is missing. I am learning Pig and have just started to move little on the advance topic.

Comment: Does your Pig Script have access to /cloudera/examples/javascripts/firstJS.js?Try moving that js file to the location where the Pig Script is and use register 'firstJS.js' using javascript as myfuncs;

Comment: I am not using Pig Script right now. All the statement e.g. "student = ...." are executed at Grunt. For testing I had given the full path in REGISTER statement as

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am executing all statements at GRUNT and not from script. For testing I have executed the REGISTER statement as register 'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/cloudera/examples/javascripts/firstJS.js' using javascript as myfuncs;, so that there is no problem in accessing the javascript file. Still Error 1070 mentioned in the original post is received.